# What is the "OEM partition" after my system one and before the free space?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

So I've just got a new ssd and used clonezilla to copy everything from one hardrive to another.

[image: Hard Drive disk management]

I want to be able to extend my hardrive to use all the memory, but there's a partition in the way. (872 MB NTFS Healthy (OEM Partition)) I know I can use third party tools to extend stuff when the partitions are not next to each other but I want to understand what this block partition is.

Is the the left over boot app from clonezilla? How can I remove it?

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to accomplish.  Any disk-management tool, including Windows Disk Management can remove the offending partition, and then resize the C: drive partition.  The big question is why did you clone a 500GB drive to a 1TB drive?

Comment: You can't remove the partition through disk management, cloned it to take the OS and such.

Answer (score 1):

As per [TypeID | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-setup-diskconfiguration-disk-modifypartitions-modifypartition-typeid) , "OEM Partition" simply means that it has a [partition type code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type) of [`0x12`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type#PID_12h), [`0x84`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type#PID_84h), [`0xDE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type#PID_DEh), [`0xFE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type#PID_FEh), or [`0xA0`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type#PID_A0h). As you can see from the corresponding table entries in Wikipedia, these partition type codes are known to be used for OEM recovery partitions (that have FAT/FAT32 FS) and for hibernation cache for various proprietary technologies (likely no general-purpose FS).

It's impossible to say anything more without looking at its contents.

---

To view a partition's contents, you need to

- Somehow guess its filesystem (and if it has a filesystem at all)

  Usually, you can guess that by looking at the hexdump of the first sector of the partition. Most filesystems have some signature "magic bytes" there.

  There are many tools that can do this, including [BootICE](http://www.softportal.com/get-32168-bootice.html), Acronis Disk Director, and `dd` (and likely GParted) from [System Rescue CD](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/).
- [Mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_(computing)) that filesystem

  This is completely specific to the OS and/or the tools. E.g.

  - In Linux (including System Rescue CD), you use `mount`.
  - Acronis Disk Director can show contents without explicit mounting but you may need to change the partition type for it to be able to guess the filesystem.
  - In Windows, you mount by assigning a letter to the partition in Disk Management. But Windows can only mount a few filesystem types that it knows of. And you need to first change the partition type to the value corresponding to that filesystem. This may break the system if the partition is in active use by some running software.

Comment: well how do I look into it? your answer hasn't helped.

Comment: @user3667111 See the update. I told you it's a whole separate question. If you get the hexdump and add it to the question, I may be able to guess what it is.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/windows/how_to_delete_an_oem_partition.htm to remove the partition.

However, it would likely be a better idea to configure the new drive correctly in the first place, then copy the partition(s) that you want.

EASUS is a really handy tool for managing disks, and is more capable than what is built-in to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

OEM partitions store system backups stored by computer manufacturers. 
For more information about OEM partition, please visit:
https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/delete-oem-partition.html
Please Note: Since the web site is not hosted by Microsoft, the link may change without notice. Microsoft does not guarantee the accuracy of this information.

Best Regards,
Daniel